# Count redundancy of answers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like so

```
 [
{_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded9a", question: "Do you like it?", answer: "yes"},
{_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded99", question: "Do you like it?", answer: "no"},
{_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda1", question: "Where are you?", answer: "home"},
{_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda0", question: "Where are you?", answer: "home"}
]
```

and I want it to be reproduced like the following:

```
[
 {
  "question": "Do you like it?",
  "answers": [{"answer": "yes", "count": 1}, {"answer": "no", "count": 1}]
 },
 {
  "question": "Where are you?",
  "answers": [{"answer": "home", "count": 2}]
 }
]
```

I have tried to solve this but i couldn't so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Array.find` to find the question-answer pair then add a *new* question-answer pair object if the pair is *not existing* or update the existing question-answer pair object.

If the question exits but the answer doesn't then simply add the new answer in the `answers` array.

If both the question and answer exists then increment the answer `count` property by 1.

If the question itself is missing then add a new object with the `question` property and `answers` property and set the `count` to `1`.

Then finally use `Array.reduce` to accumulate the objects into an array.

```js
const data = [
{_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded9a", question: "Do you like it ?", answer: "yes"},
{_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded99", question: "Do you like it ?", answer: "no"},
{_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda1", question: "Where are you ?", answer: "home"},
{_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda0", question: "Where are you ?", answer: "home"}
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, {question, answer}) => {
 qFound = acc.find(qa => qa.question === question);
 if(qFound){ 
   ansFound = qFound.answers.find(ans => ans.answer === answer);
   if(ansFound){
      ansFound.count = ansFound.count + 1;
   }else{
      qFound.answers.push({answer, count:1});
   }
 }else{
   acc.push({
     question,
     answers: [].concat({answer, count: 1})
  });
 }
 return acc;
},[]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reduce` to create objects grouped by question and answer values and then later to discard the `keys` use `Object.values()`

```js
const input =  [
  {_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded9a", question: "Do you like it ?", answer: "yes"},
  {_id: "5ca8b8ca0f1b2f54646ded99", question: "Do you like it ?", answer: "no"},
  {_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda1", question: "Where are you ?", answer: "home"},
  {_id: "5ca8b8f80f1b2f54646deda0", question: "Where are you ?", answer: "home"}
];

const groupByQuestionAndAnswers = Object.values(input.reduce((accu, {question, answer}) => {
  if(!accu[question]) 
    accu[question] = {question};
  if(!accu[question][answer]) 
    accu[question][answer] = {answer, count: 0};
  accu[question][answer].count += 1;

  return accu;
}, {}));

const output = groupByQuestionAndAnswers.map(({question, ...res}) => {
  return {question, answers: Object.values(res)};
});

console.log(output);
```